# Entropy of discrete and continuous uniform distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, information-theory, uniform-distribution, entropy

Despite a similar post here, I read that the entropy of a uniformly distributed *discrete* random variable is always log base $2$ of the number of observations in the dataset, $H(X) = \log(N)$. Is this also true for a uniformly distributed *continuous* r.v.?

Comment: Well, [which version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Variants) of entropy are you talking about?

Comment: let's start with the most well-known/implemented renditions of differential entropy, whichever they may be. I heard one of them is $log(b-a)$ for continuous uniforms?

Answer (score 0):

Think about it.

A real number between $0$ and $1$ is able to contain *infinite* information. Just encode any symbol of the alphabet with the decimal representation 3 digit ascii symbols for example.

Entropy of continous distribution means how much information you need to store just for the shape of the distribution. You will need to add as many extra bits for whatever precision you will want.

Comment: i don't know ascii symbols. what does a real number between 0 and 1 mean with regard to discrete or continuous uniform r.v.'s? is there no analytical solution for the continuous case as there is for the discrete case?

Comment: It seems you may benefit from thinking about the concepts a bit more before asking questions.